# A practical problem about wiring technique

Tags: soldering, wiring, enclosure

When assembling an electronic enclosure and wiring, I encounter a section which I share the diagram below:

[image]

So as you see above there are three switches where some of pins are connected each other.

And here how they look like in real:

[image: parts]

If I solder pin x to pin y how can I obtain the z output? I though of soldering x to y and also x to z but seems not reliable.

Same with p q and r. One pin can only take one wire so it seems not a good idea to solder two wires into pin p.

So I'm stuck with how to realize the schematic in practice by soldering or any other trick/tool/part. What could be a robust reliable solution?

Comment: So connect the tail, or Z, at X or Y.

Comment: x and y are pins to be soldered and they can take only one wire in. you mean tail from x and tail from y and z to be combined? But Im asking "practically" how? By special screw or solder ect?

Comment: Two tails could be twisted but in this case three tails needs to be combined.

Comment: I have been known to solder one wire to each face of the pin - depends on your soldering skills though. And have also managed 4 wires: two on each side. Don't overheat though...

Comment: How about this type of connector?:  https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0097/6784/5966/products/3WCN5_893x893.jpg?v=1561652132 =

Comment: Solder a wire to x, leave the other end open. Solder a wire to y, leave the other end open. take a 3rd wire for z, twist and solder it to the open ends of the other 2 wires. Cover the joint with heat-shrink.

Comment: @brhans One practical question regarding your suggestion. Should I first twist the open ends of x and y and then twist the z with the twisted xy OR should I twist open ends of x, y and z altogether? (before applying solder)

Comment: Depends on how you want the finished joint to look. If you put all 3 together with all the wires exiting the joint on the same side then I'd twist all 3 in one operation. But if you want the z wire to exit the joint on the opposite side from x & y, then I'd twist those 2 together 1st, and then twist z to go out the other side.

Comment: For the right-most switch, I would solder two wires through the hole in the tab.  For the center, I would also solder two wires in one pin.  It is very common to solder more than one wire to a switch or connector terminal.

Comment: @brhans  If you look at my diagram what you say in your second suggestion matches better then. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PeterBennett Sorry being inaccurate but the big one in the middle in the photo is the right-most connector in diagram.

Comment: How thick should the wires be?

Comment: @datenheim 22 AWG (multicore 7 cores)

Comment: Such thin wires! Well, just drill them up and solder them directly to the pins of the connectors etc. You will move the connection points of your sketch to any of the pins, wherever it fits best. Or didn't I understand your point?

Comment: @datenheim Sorry some will be 18 AWG(multicore) for high currents.

Comment: You could have added some more details to your original question. Let us know your experience level in wiring things up. You might consider using heat-shrink tubing after soldering to get some protection...

Comment: @datenheim Yes it could be much detailed in question. Also these kind of practical info is super difficult to find in web search and yet very critical.

Comment: >> Sorry some will be 18 AWG(multicore) for high current  ....    Are the switches rated to handle the expected current???

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the additional information you revealed in your comments. Also note that the solder lugs on the components, particularly the one on the right, has elongated holes that can accommodate two or more strands of hook-up wire. And another point - please provide data sheets or more complete info on these components. I doubt they are all switches - more likely a switch, a connector, and a circuit breaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, these are three different devices, which have their own unique specifications and terminal types.

The one on the right has three terminals, each of which has elongated holes which can accommodate two or more wire strands. It appears to be a low current device so #22 AWG should be sufficient.

The device on the left has two fairly substantial quick-disconnect (QD) terminals, and the proper crimp lugs may be the best way to connect wires, but solder can be used as well. However, they are often nickel-plated and can be harder to solder, and too much heat may melt the body of the component and damage its internal parts.

The item in the middle almost certainly is a connector, and it has cup type solder terminals which require some skill to properly solder. They appear to be rather large and the connector is probably rated 15 amps or more, so #16 AWG or heavier wire may be needed. It is probably not a good idea to attempt connection of more than one wire to each terminal. Here is an manufacturer's sheet about such connector pins, and a video tutorial on proper soldering technique.

[image: Cup type solder terminals]

https://www.mill-max.com/products/new/solder-cup-connectors-and-terminal-pins

Comment: Those old school soldering videos are often great. Although regarding soldering of the connector, also make sure it is fixed (in a vise or equivalent) before soldering. What they didn't mention either is that you should apply solder to the wires too after peeling them to the correct length.